# How to use JavaScript to syn time from some online time server?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a mobile application and I need to sync the time with a centralized online server . How can I go about doing that? I can only use JavaScript, no Ajax/ActiveX/Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [recently answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380365/how-to-handle-dst-and-timezones-in-javascript/9382081#9382081), but your time values should be retrieved from `(new Date()).getTime()`. Send these values to the server and store only these long values. Then send these values to each client and convert them to the Javascript `Date` object again like this. `var x = new Date(longnum)`. Then you can display the time in the users locale format: `x.toLocaleString()`.

Comment: `Date.toLocaleString()` is implementation dependent and varies greatly between browsers (most completely ignore local settings other than timezone offset). Far better to create an unambigous date string (e.g. 23-Feb-2012 or similar) and use that everywhere.

Comment: I don't quite catch on. Does (new Date()).getTime() contact the server to get time?

Comment: @antonpug: No.  You need to use AJAX.

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean? I am not sure how can I pull the epoch time from somewhere online and just save it as a string?

Comment: @antonpug: You need to either find a JSONP time service or write your own server-side script that returns a time from wherever you want (to avoid the Same Origin Policy)

Comment: What?? No, you DO NOT need a time service... what's wrong with calling (new Date()).getTime() in the browser? It returns the time since UTC epoch. My answer explains what you need to do.

Comment: @JPRichardson: He's specifically asking for a time from an online server.  Read the question.

Comment: @SLaks: You should read the question as well. He literally is asking to "sync time with an online server". I guess what really matters is what he really means. Or, more importantly, what problem is he trying to solve. My guess is that he isn't aware that the browser provides enough info (UTC time) for most applications.

Comment: @JPRichardson why would you rely on your user having an accurate clock if accurate time is important?

Comment: @Pointy agreed. But nowhere is does it say "accurate time". To be fair though, I think that we can assume that that's what he wants. Today's modern operating systems typically sync with a time server, so I'd say that if getting time from the client isn't needed for anything mission critical, the time from the client can be trusted. The real problem is that he didn't articulate the problem that he wants to solve, and that's what I was trying to get at. Good point that you added though, and important for anyone to consider.