# Is there any way to get time from some centralized location using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap app, which can only use HTML/CSS/JS, and I need to pull time from some centralized time server using strictly JAVASCRIPT, maybe somehow using JSON? AJAX? Point is I need a good server to use and how to set up the script - I feel like it is really easy but I just don't know...

Comment: Why not just use your own server and have your server run NTP?

Comment: Can't use our own server - financial, time, and other constraints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use JavaScript to syn time from some online time server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459603/how-to-use-javascript-to-syn-time-from-some-online-time-server)

Comment: http://viv.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?EbayTime , scrape for "The official eBay Time is now:" And before you shout at me: Yes, this is a joke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JavaScript library like http://jehiah.cz/a/ntp-for-javascript can grab from any public free NTP server.  Just pick one and off you go!

Comment: That only works if your own server can provide the NTP synchronization. You can't just grab stuff from random servers from JavaScript in a browser unless they're already set up to provide something like JSONP, or nowadays a CORS setup.